# In Excel, how do I rearrange names in a column to be side by side with matching names in an adjacent column?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

For example, if I have data like this:

```
06/10       |      06/11
========================
andrew      |     julia

julia       |     brian

zack        |     andrew

brian       |     amber

phillip     |

amber       |

jess        |
```

How do I obtain the following result or a close version?

```
06/10        06/11
---------------------
andrew    |   andrew     

julia     |   julia

zack      |       

brian     |   brian    

phillip   |

amber     |   amber

jess      |
```

Comment: Could you use a 3rd column? If so, it could be done very easily with a `Vlookup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the main column is "A", you could go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("mysheetname") '<--| change "mysheetname" with your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) '<--| change "A2:A" and "A" with proper first relevant row of the first data column
            ReDim myArr(1 To .Rows.Count)
            For Each cell In .Cells
                myArr(cell.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1) =  Iif(.Offset(, 1).Find(what:=cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing, cell.Offset(,1).Value, cell.Value)
            Next cell
            .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(myArr)
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: user3598756, is there a way to for every adjacent column with out retyping the code and changing the column letter. That answer worked by the way, so I gratefully appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Since my answer fulfilled your _original_ question, then please mark it as accepted. Thank you. As for the new request you have to start a new question.

Comment: user3598756, what part of your deletes the cell value if there is no match in the previous column?

Comment: it 's in `.Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(myArr)`, which is overwriting the entire range given by `.Offset(, 1)` (relative to `.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)`) with `myArr` array values, which on its turn has values filled with `If Not .Offset(, 1).Find(what:=cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then myArr(cell.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1) = cell.Value` thus filling it only at indexes corresponding to `True` check results

Comment: oh okay, i see. what do i do in order to prevent the code from deleting a name in a cell if that name does not match with another in a previous column

Comment: First of all, i appreciate the help. However, the new edited answer took the names from the first column that are not in the second column and put them into the second column. Also the names in the columns were not matched.

Comment: it's time you play yourself with the code. it's also a way (the best, IMHO) to actually learn VBA (or any other language). which is the real purpose of this site

Comment: do you recommend any good sites or sources to help learn the commands and terminology and stuff? Also I thank you for your help and tips

Comment: I really enjoyed "Excel 2010 Power Programming with VBA" by John Walkenbach. I Also learned (and still am learning) a lot from this site. Both with a lot of trial&error routine